# How to insert bulk records after modification in to a another table using Apache Camel and Spring boot

Tags: apache, apache-camel, esb, spring-camel

I'm using apache camel and spring boot to implement the integration flow between two tables. Source table includes more than 1000 records. What I want to do is after doing some modification in to the source data those data should insert to a another table in the same database. I'm stuck with the data insert stage.

```
    <camelContext id="Integrator" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="hello">
            <from id="timer" uri="timer:test?period={{timer.period}}"/>
            <setBody id="query">
                <constant>SELECT * FROM abc WHERE code = 'MDV1'</constant>
            </setBody>
            <log id="log_1" message="log msg"/>
            <to id="jdbc_con" uri="jdbc:dataSource"/>
            <process id="changebody" ref="editPayload"/>
            <log id="log_2" message="process row ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Updated:

This is not the exact answer I wanted. But this flow can insert the record from source table to target. In this solution record will be insert in to target table one by one. I wanted to insert as bulk in the final stage instead of inserting one by one.

```
<camelContext id="Integrator"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="data_transfer">
            <from id="timer" uri="timer:abcStaging?period={{timer.period}}" />
            <setBody id="select_query">
                <constant>select * from abc</constant>
            </setBody>
            <to id="jdbc_con_select" uri="jdbc:dataSource" />
            <split>
                <simple>${body}</simple>
                <process id="change_body" ref="editPayload" />
                <to id="jdbc_con_insert" uri="sql:{{sql.abcStaging}}" />
                <log id="log_1" message="Inserted abcStaging" />
            </split>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

properties file:

```
sql.abcStaging =insert into abcStaging (id, rate) values (:#id, :#rate)
```

editPayload Bean:

```
public class ChangePayload implements Processor {

  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    LinkedHashMap linkedHashMap = (LinkedHashMap) exchange.getIn().getBody();
    Map<String, Object> staging = new HashMap<>();

    /* data changing logics */

    staging.put("id", "id");
    staging.put("rate", "rate");

    exchange.getOut().setBody(staging);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could I ask why you want to do this in Camel if it is from one table to another? Why not just SQL to do the whole operation?

Comment: @DariusX. In the real scenario there are complex logics which difficult to handle with SQL to edit payload before insert target table. This is a sub part of a entire integration flow. In the real scenario these two are diffrent remote databases. This is not a simple table coping from one database to another. Do you have any idea for alternatives except sql operation?

Comment: I would run the record set through a split insert them in parallel. Should not be difficult however I am not sure if I am missing something as your question is a bit vague. Where do you get stuck on it?

Comment: @Namphibian jdbc_con returns a ArrayList into editPayload bean. Simply I want to iterate this ArrayList using <loop>. So I can manage payload editing part with in the <loop> row by row in to target table. Now I'm stuck in ArryaList iteration part using <loop>

Comment: You acn split the array list. Look at splitter EIP.

Comment: I updated the question as above. Is there any way to execute update step as bulk instead of inserting one by one in to the target table?

Answer (score 0):

If your main requirement is to do execute a single bulk query, you may have to build the query yourself, in an Aggregator.

If your DBMS supports syntax like:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (F1, F2) Values (a1, b1), (a2,b2)
```

then an aggregator could build up that large string. (This would not be feasible if you have (say) 10,000 or 100,000 rows since it might cross a statement-size limit.) The other downside is that one would need to build the value clauses knowing data-types...not sure if one can parameterize something like that.